# File disappeared on Linux. Search says it's still there

Tags: linux

So I was editing a cpp file in sublime on my linux machine and I'm not sure what I did or what happened but all of a sudden the file disappeared on sublime. So it went to it's directory to open it back up but it's not there.

I did a quick search for it and it says it's says it's still in the the directory it was in but it doesn't show the actual file.

I don't think it's hidden. Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Try to open in on recent files in sublime or check file access modes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chmod` to give permission to use the file in user.

```
chmod 777 <filename>
```

Before running this command you have to open root privilege by using `sudo su` command.